# Output fail/else condition

Tags: arrays, bash

I have script that checks the availability of package on my server, it iterate through array and should return `[INSTALLED]` if it is. Below script is modified to the basic to give you understanding what'd it do.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a prog=("mysql-server" "apache2" "php" "ufw")
declare -a snap=("beer")

for f in "${!prog[@]}"; do
  for connect in "${snap[@]}"; do
    ssh jan@"$connect" /bin/bash <<- EOF
    if [ \$(dpkg --get-selections | grep -E "(^|\s)${prog[$f]}(\$|\s)" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then
      prog[$f]="${prog[$f]} [INSTALLED]" # The program is already installed
      echo "\${prog[@]}"
    else
      echo "False"
    fi
EOF
    done
  done
```

This should return the package name and `[INSTALLED]` suffix if it is installed, otherwise it will only return the package name.

I expect the output to be:

```
mysql-server [INSTALLED]
apache2 [INSTALLED]
php [INSTALLED]
ufw
```

Turns out the output was:

```
mysql-server [INSTALLED]
apache2 [INSTALLED]
php [INSTALLED]
False
```

`ufw` package is not installed on the server, I expect it to return `ufw` instead `Not installed`— if I remove the else clause altogether, `ufw` would not be appear on the output at all.

Comment: not sure I understand the issue ... the `else` block is coded to print `False` and that appears to be what it does; if different output is desired then update the `else` block to output the desired output; what am I missing?

Comment: `if [ \$(dpkg --get-selections | grep -E "(^|\s)${prog[$f]}(\$|\s)" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]` just do `if dpkg --get-selections | grep -qE "(^|\s)${prog[$f]}(\$|\s)"; then`. But just to check if a package is installed, I think you can just `if dpkg -l "${prog[$f]}"; then`

Comment: Exactly that. `[` is an alias to the `test` command. If you wouldn't use `test`, don't use `[`.

Comment: Your script has other problems as well. You don't need to modify `prog` at all; just output `$f` on each iteration, possibly with `[INSTALLED]` following it if the condition is true.

Comment: @chepner That seems like nice idea, but how would I do that ? Sorry I'm not really strong on bash language.

Comment: Your if statement would just set `status="[INSTALLED]"` or `status=""`, based on the result of `dpkg`. After the `if`, you would unconditionally execute `printf '%s %s\n' "$f" "$status"`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you very much ! that's working, I've never thought to do this. And its so much faster than before

Comment: @chepner But I faced a new problem, the output seems to be doubled as I add new server in `$snap` array, it understandable because the ssh loops through the array, but how to merge it to one ? Should I ask new question ?

Comment: Perhaps you want `connect` in the output string as well, so you can differentiate between `mysql-server` being installed on one server or the other.

Comment: @chepner Actually, I have done that before, but the result just weren't [right](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HzB4xHFGRx/), I want it to merge to one line so theres no duplicate entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205753/discussion-between-johnny-and-chepner).