# How to merge duplicate entries that produced by for loop

Tags: arrays, bash

Following my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59664480/output-fail-else-condition) which got closed— basically I have a script that check availability of packages on target server, the target server and the packages have been stored to an array.

```sh
declare -a prog=("gdebi" "firefox" "chromium-browser" "thunar")
declare -a snap=("beer2" "beer3")

# checkvar=$(
for f in "${prog[@]}"; do
  for connect in "${snap[@]}"; do
    ssh lg@"$connect" /bin/bash <<- EOF
      if dpkg --get-selections | grep -qE "(^|\s)"$f"(\$|\s)"; then
          status="[INSTALLED] [$connect]"
      else
          status=""
      fi
      printf '%s %s\n' "$f" "\$status"
EOF
    done
  done
```

With the help of fellow member here, I've made several fix to original script, script ran pretty well— except there's one problem, the output contain duplicate entries.

```
gdebi [INSTALLED] [beer2]
gdebi 
firefox [INSTALLED] [beer2]
firefox [INSTALLED] [beer3]
chromium-browser [INSTALLED] [beer2]
chromium-browser [INSTALLED] [beer3]
thunar 
thunar
```

I know it this is normal behavior, as `for` pass multiple server from `snap` array, making `ssh` travel to all the two server.

Considering that the script checks same package for two server, I want the output to be merged.

- If `beer2` have `firefox` packages, but `beer3` doesn't.

  ```
  firefox [INSTALLED] [beer2]
  ```
- If `beer3` have `firefox` packages, but `beer2` doesn't.

  ```
  firefox [INSTALLED] [beer3]
  ```
- If both `beer2` and `beer3` have the packages.

  ```
  firefox [INSTALLED] [beer2, beer3]
  ```

  or

  ```
  firefox [INSTALLED] [beer2] [beer3]
  ```
- If both `beer2` and `beer3` doesn't have the package, it will return without extra parameter.

  ```
  firefox
  ```

Sound like an easy task, but for the love of god I can't find how to achieve this, here's list of things I have tried.

- Try to manipulate the `for` loops.
- Try putting return value after one successful loops (exit code).
- Try nested `if`.
  All of the above doesn't seem to work, I haven't tried changing/manipulate the return string as I'm not really experienced with some text processing such as: `awk`, `sed`, `tr` and many others.

Can anyone shows how It's done ? Would really mean the world to me.

Comment: As a side note, why do you use `for f in "${!prog[@]}"` and then `${prog[$f]}` instead of `for f in "${prog[@]}"` and then just `$f`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Woah I missed that, that's  from my previous code which modify the array element if it was installed, thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure Bash 4+ solution using associative array to store hosts the program is installed on:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A hosts_with_package=(["gdebi"]="" ["firefox"]="" ["chromium-browser"]="" ["thunar"]="")
declare -a hosts=("beer2" "beer3")

# Collect installed status
# Iterate all hosts
for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
  # Read the output of dpkg --get-selections with searched packages
  while IFS=$' \t' read -r package status; do

    # Test weather package is installed on host
    if [ "$status" = "install" ]; then

      # If no host listed for package, create first entry
      if [ -z "${hosts_with_package[$package]}" ]; then
        # Record the first host having the package installed
        hosts_with_package["$package"]="$host"
      else
        # Additional hosts are concatenated as CSV
        hosts_with_package["$package"]="${hosts_with_package[$package]}, $host"
      fi
    fi
    # Feed the whole loop with the output of the dpkg --get-selections for packages names
    # Packages names are the index of the hosts_with_package array
  done < <(ssh "lg@$host" dpkg --get-selections "${!hosts_with_package[@]}")
done

# Output results
# Iterate the package name keys
for package in "${!hosts_with_package[@]}"; do
  # Print package name without newline
  printf '%s' "$package"
  # If package is installed on some hosts
  if [ -n "${hosts_with_package[$package]}" ]; then
    # Continue the line with installed hosts
    printf ' [INSTALLED] [%s]' "${hosts_with_package[$package]}"
  fi
  # End with a newline
  echo
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making several ssh connections in nested loops consider this change

```
prog=( mysql-server apache2 php ufw )
snap=( localhost )


for connect in ${snap[@]}; do
    ssh $connect "
        progs=( ${prog[@]} )
        for prog in \${progs[@]}; do
            dpkg -l | grep -q \$prog && echo \"\$prog [INSTALLED]\" || echo \"\$prog\"
        done
    "
done
```

Comment: This won't tell the OP if a single app is installed on several servers, but it's still better with less connections

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Ivan answer

```sh
#!/bin/bash

prog=( "gdebi" "firefox" "chromium-browser" "thunar" )
snap=( "beer2" "beer3" )

# First, retrieve the list on installed program for each host
for connect in ${snap[@]}; do
    ssh lg@"$connect" /bin/bash >/tmp/installed.${connect} <<- EOF
      progs=( "${prog[@]}" )
      for prog in \${progs[@]}; do
          dpkg --get-selections | awk -v pkg=\$prog '\$1 == pkg && \$NF ~ /install/ {print \$1}'
      done
EOF
done

# Filter the previous results to format the output as you need
awk '{
    f = FILENAME;
    gsub(/.*\./,"",f);
    a[$1] = a[$1] "," f
}
END {
    for (i in a)
        print i ":[" substr(a[i],2) "]"
}' /tmp/installed.*

rm /tmp/installed.*
```

Example of output :

```
# With prog=( bash cat sed tail something firefox-esr )
firefox-esr:[localhost]
bash:[localhost,localhost2]
sed:[localhost,localhost2]
```